# Clap switch working

Tags: circuit-analysis

This is a clap switch circuit, made from pcb

[image]

In the picture, it is a clap switch that I made from pcb. It is working fine in gpb. As I didn't make any changes, I want to know how it is working!? If you can explain it( though I need a brief description) in short, it would be a great help to me! Thank you!

Comment: I love the little bridges where the wires cross.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact  Q1 & Q2 are drawn with C-E leads reversed in your sketch is wrong....

- Q1 is high gain common emitter with HPF input.
- Q2 and  Q3 act as a pulse comparator and pulse stretch with positive feedback to become a flip flop or Bistable multivibrator using AC couple to both bases for negative peaks. (clap clap to @AltAir)
- Q4 is a low current switch

I think this schematic wins my approval for the ugliest orthogonal schematic award of the year. (even after I improved contrast and rotated it)

Anyone else agree?

Here is a similar cct. but for left to right and Positive at top here is an exception where PNP Emitters are positive but switch to ground with a negative supply. YOu can easily recognize that swapping V- to V+ and PNP to NPN makes the same circuit work.  **(ground below cct. is logical  way to draw schematics.)**

[image]

Comment: It does fill the sheet of paper up nicely, though :)

Comment: Q2 and Q3 are a bistable multivibrator circuit.

Comment: Thanks for your compliment. But I made this circuit just to simplify for me, i don't have such experience to make any circuit or its schematic. If you can help me draw its schematic in better way then plz tell me! Thank you

Comment: For starters, draw the positive supply voltage as a straight line above everything else, and the negative supply voltage (ground) as a straight line below everything else.    Then put the microphone as far to the left as possible and the LEDs as far to the right as possible.  Then moves components around to make the wires shorter and easier to trace.

Comment: The normal convention is that higher voltage supply rails are above lower voltage supply rails.   Inputs at the left and outputs at the right.  Signals travel from left to right, except for feedback which travels the opposite direction.

Comment: @OskarSkog but is it ok to show resistors or any other component in both horizontal and vertical?

Comment: @user148637:  Yes.  Horizontal and vertical are both perfectly fine, just choose the right one.  In some cases 45° angles can be appropriate too, bridge rectifiers for example.

Answer (score 0):

[image: The similar circuit in readable form.]

A similar circuit in readable form that works on the same principle with a brief description [link](http://www.circuitstune.com/2013/02/clap-switch-circuit-with-onoff-220v.html)